# Facebook Feed error without any info passed to the callback and no change made on the app-side

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-unity-sdk

I've just launched a game made with Unity3D which use the Facebook SDK for multiple purposes. Before uploading my app to the Appstore for Apple review, I've fully tested it on iOS 6 and iOS 7 and everything was working perfectly.

A week later, after Apple reviewed and accepted this application, I've made it available to the public but it seems that one of my social features based on Facebook isn't working anymore.

More specifically, the Feed method launch the Facebook app properly and display the feed information as expected, then my callback on Unity side is called (but the result.Text and result.Error are empty) but when I go back to the Facebook app, a error message is shown and obviously nothing is posted. The error message is : "Oops, Something Went Wrong. There was a problem posting your status. We've logged the error and will look into if".

I've been looking for a answer for this but can't find anything as I think the error is handled by Facebook and I don't have any log.

The really strange part is that I didn't change anything between now and when I first tested my app and other features of Facebook (like retrieving Facebook friends for displaying their scores, etc...) and Feed dialog on Android work perfectly (which is leading me to believe that it's not related to my Facebook app configuration).

The only explanation I can find for now is related to an update of the Facebook app released a few days ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, everything seems to be working again without any intervention. It seems reasonable to think that the problem came directly from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Turned out the bundle ID at developers.facebook.com didn't exactly match the bundle ID in XCode.